# The Windows start menu items don't expand unless I click on it

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I use windows 7 Classic Start Menu ([Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/)) and I set the menu delay to 1 ms:

[image]

However, from time to time, the Windows start menu items stop to automatically expand on mouseover unless I click on them (video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4_QvAzJ8WM).

Any idea why this issue appears? Restarting explorer.exe solves it but I wonder why it appears in the first place.

Note that killing the Classic Start Menu process don't solve the issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Classic Shell.  I would report the problem to the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is fixed in Classic Shell 4.0.4.

Comment: Thanks, I had 4.0.2: I've just upgraded to 4.0.4, I'll accept the answer in ~one week in bug doesn't show up again.